# QT Release version not showing video

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to deploy my windows GUI application. I ran the executable through DependecyWalker and added all the missing DLL files, so the program starts up. I had troubles with images not saving to file after downloading. but after I added the "plugins\imageformats" folder to my program folder everything with images is working like a charm. My problem is now that DependecyWalker does not report any missing DLLs, but my app does not show the video. The QVideoWidget is just white. It works fine on my development computer through QT Creator, but no success when testing the release on my virtual machine.

Does anyone know which folders and/or dlls I am missing for videos to show up? I used the windeployqt tool. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have two questions please ask them separately (note that some people may have use Qt's web part, but not the `QVideoWidget` and vice-versa). Consider also creating a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Have you tried WinDeployQt?  Also see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: As I wrote in my question, yes. I tried it, but thanks.

Comment: Try using Process Explorer procexp.exe (google to find it) on running process to see what dll files it has loaded. With it you can find out if the deployed application hasn't found some plugins, which are found when you run it in dev env.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy folders plugins\mediaservice and plugins\playlistformats to your app folder. Then it should work. You can add this line to the .pro

CONFIG += console

to see what wrong when running in vm. At last, I would recommend using [vlc-qt](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt), with which you can deploy on XP easily.

Comment: I used the windeployqt tool, and it added all those folders needed from the plugins folder. Even though the folders are there, no success.

Comment: I thought about vlc-qt initially, but wanted to try VLCs native videoplayer. I implemented vlc-qt instead. It plays on my virtual machine.

Comment: Congratulations@AndyH